# submit button does not post when its attributes were changed

Tags: javascript, onclick, form-submit

I am using a form  and a submit button in it to call a post request to server in html

In submit button, I use onclick event to change something in UI before posting request. Everything is fine when I do not change anything to the submit button, it posts request successfully.
But if I change anything in submit button such as value, disable attribute,... then it does not post request

Here is my code

```html
<form action="url"method="post">
    <input type="submit" onclick="return onClick(event)">
</form>
```

js code that does not post request

```js
function onClick(e) {
    const submit = e.target  // or = this
    submit.value = "Clicked"
    submit.disabled = true
    return true
}
```

js code that posts request successfully

```js
function onClick(e) {
    alert("Clicked")
    return true
}
```

Could somebody tell me the reason why it does not post successfully and how to post with UI change like above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `submit` method to achieve the result.

-> Assign `id` to the button and form element then get the element like,

```
const btn = document.getElementById('btn');
const form = document.getElementById('form');
```

It is always recommended to use [**addEventListener()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) method in javascript instead of making it in HTML template.

```
form.addEventListener('submit', onSubmit)
```

-> Now you can change the value of an attribute in submit method like,

```
function onSubmit(){
    btn.value = "Clicked";
    btn.disabled = true;
    return true
}
```

Working **snippet** as follows,

```js
const btn = document.getElementById('btn');
const form = document.getElementById('form');

function onSubmit(){
    btn.value = "Clicked";
    btn.disabled = true;
    return true
}

form.addEventListener('submit', onSubmit)
```

```html
<form id="form" action="url" method="post">
    <input type="submit" id="btn">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Whether a form sends a POST or GET request is based on its `method` attribute. Try changing your form to

```
<form action="url" method="post">
    <input type="submit" onclick="return onClick(event)">
</form>
```

Comment: sorry, my confusion. But even if I changed it to method then it still can't post request

Answer (score 0):

another solution from me, I found it myself and many thanks to @Maniraj Murugan for your help above: use input type="button" instead, and in onclick event, use form.submit() to submit manually

```html
<form action="url"method="post">
    <input type="button" onclick="return onClick(event)">
</form>
```

and in onClick event

```js
function onSubmit(e){
    const btn = e.target
    btn.value = "Clicked"
    btn.disabled = true
    const form = document.getElementById('form')
    form.submit()
}
```